# differentiate $y=\cot^3 (\pi-\theta)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $y=\cot^3 (\pi-\theta)$ find $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$

I was trying to solve it following way.

$$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=3\cot^2(\pi-\theta). -1$$

There's actually one constant. So, I simply don't know how to deal with it. I had try simple way. Is it correct answer?

---

Oh! Sorry! I missed. I am adding those lines what I tried instead of removing them.

$$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=3\cot^2(\pi-\theta). -\csc^2 (\pi-\theta) . -1$$
$$=3\cot^2(\pi-\theta)csc^2 (\pi-\theta)$$

Is it correct answer?

Comment: Apply the chain rule. You also need to take derivative of $\cot (\pi - \theta)$

Comment: Let $f(x)=\cot x$ and $g(\theta) = \pi-\theta$. Then you want the derivative of $f(g(\theta))^3$. Apply the chain rule.

Comment: @rogerl I have edited my question.

Comment: @MathLover I have edited my question..

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: Looks good noice !

Comment: you can also write it by simplifying $\cot (\pi - \theta) = - \cot \theta, \csc (\pi - \theta) = \csc \theta$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Steps:

1. Using chain rule, we have:
   $$\frac{df(\theta)}{d\theta}=\frac{d\cot^3(\pi-\theta)}{d\cot(\pi-\theta)}\frac{d\cot(\pi-\theta)}{d(\pi-\theta)}\frac{d(\pi-\theta)}{d\theta}.$$
2. To differentiate $\cot$ (the middle term in the equation above), apply the quotient rule.